# Increment the number of votes button

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am coding in c# asp.net using razor technology, I am still getting errors in designing a button that each click considered as vote , and I should display that! But i cant get it in a right logic :(

Here is my code in the view

```
using (Html.BeginForm("OpenBidPanelOnItem", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{          
  <button name="Vote" value="Vote" style="background-color: green; width: 60px">
    <b style="color:snow">Vote</b>
  </button>
  <h3>Total Votes for @registerMember.UserName is : @Model.NumberOfVotes votes</h3>
}
```

Where should I increment the number of votes by 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have a OpenBidPanelOnItem action on your HomeController and persist the change to datastore for next render. It would look something like this in C#.

```
public ActionResult OpenBidPanelOnItem() {
   var model = GetModelFromSomewhere();
   model.NumberOfVotes++;
   SaveModelToPersistentDataStore(model);
}
```

Your button I assume will need to be your submit button so add type="submit" to the button attributes.

Hope this helps and makes sense.

Gareth

Comment: I got errors, its a mess at the moment, i have tried everything , nothing is working, this is what is in my home controller .. I have updated my post thanks

Comment: Your action name in the controller differs from the action name in your BeginForm function in your view. You'll also need to mark the action with a `[HttpPost]` attribute on the line about the action signature.

Comment: OHHH YEAH ! I didnt realized ! thanks

Comment: :) glad I could help, can you upvote me or mark me as the answer, I'm after some reputation points so I can start commenting!